# what <Carousel.Item> means?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i see in reactBootstrap in the carousel component this code

```
            <Carousel.Item>
                <img
                    className="d-block w-100"
                    src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
                    alt="First slide"
                />
                <Carousel.Caption>
                    <h3>First slide label</h3>
                    <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
```

and i do not understand what is this `<element.something>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type)

> You can also refer to a React component using dot-notation from within
> JSX. This is convenient if you have a single module that exports many
> React components. For example, if MyComponents.DatePicker is a
> component, you can use it directly from JSX with:
>
> ```
> import React from 'react';
>
> const MyComponents = {
>   DatePicker: function DatePicker(props) {
>     return <div>Imagine a {props.color} datepicker here.</div>;
>   }
> }
>
> function BlueDatePicker() {
>   return <MyComponents.DatePicker color="blue" />;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

<Carousel.Item> is kind of self descriptive, it means each item info/details among the multiple items.